# Weird behaviour in evaluating spaces in string in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, busybox

I have the following string in bash

```
pseed="  0  0  0 45 46 78 99100" #there is 2 spaces between 2 zeros
```

My string contains a number in each bloc of 3 charachters. if the number < 100 then the number is padded with spaces. And I want to extract all numbers with a common format `${pseed:3*i:3}` and I want to use this format in a while loop

when I want to display the first 0 with:

```
$echo ${pseed:0:3}
0
```

I get a `0` as expected

but when I dsplay the second 0 with

```
$echo ${pseed:3:6}
0 0
```

I get `0 0` and it's unexpected.

What's happening?

I remarked that when displaying:

```
$pseed="  0  0  0  0"
$echo $pseed
0 0 0 0
```

there is only one space between zeros.

How to avoid a such behaviour in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your variable expansion to prevent arbitrary runs of whitespace from being treated as a single word separator.

```
$ pseed="  0  0  0 45 46 78 99100"
$ echo x${pseed:3:6}x
x 0 0x
$ echo "x${pseed:3:6}x"
x  0  0x
```

A `bash` extension to the `read` built-in command makes it a little easier to extract fixed-width fields from a string:

```
arr=()
while read -n 3 num; do   # -n 3: read 3 characters at a time
    arr+=($num)
done <<< "$pseed"         # Quote to preserve whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

From documentation available [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
${string:position:length}

Extracts $length characters of substring from $string at $position.
```

I believe what you should be trying to echo is `${pseed:3:3}` to get a single 0.

As for the second part of the question, echo sees 4 parameters and prints them out with a single space in between. In order to preserve the whitespace, you need to use `echo "$pseed"`.

Comment: as you can see my string contain a number in each bloc of 3 charachters. if the number < 100 then the number is padded with spaces

Comment: and I want to extract all numbers with a common format `${pseed:3*i:3*i+3}` and I want to use this format in a while loop

Comment: In this case, the 3rd parameter is always a *3*: `${pseed:3*i:3}`. Remember, the 3rd parameter is length, not end position.

Comment: you are right my expression was wrong. I updated in the question